# Angular 2 DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, search, datatables

I'm trying to work with Jquery DataTable on angular 2 app, I've installed it successfully but still not work and I don't know why !

here is my component.ts file code:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
const $ = require('jquery');
const dt = require ('datatables.net');
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cartographie',
  templateUrl: './cartographie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cartographie.component.css', '../../../../node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css']
})

export class CartographieComponent implements OnInit {
  public data;
  rootNode: any;

  constructor(rootNode: ElementRef, private http: Http) {
    this.rootNode = rootNode;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
    const el = $(this.rootNode.nativeElement).find('#example')[0];
    $('#example').DataTable();
  }

  private getData() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost/ang.php/')
      .subscribe(res => this.data = res.json());
  }
}
```

and here is the component.html file code :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title text-center">
        <h3>Cartographie</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col lg-12">
        <div class="example ">
          <table class="table table-striped display" id="example" >
            <thead >
            <tr>
              <th>Nom du poste</th>
              <th>Emploie</th>
              <th>Metier</th>
              <th>Famile</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody *ngFor="let grid of data">
            <tr class="gradeA">
              <td>{{ grid.NomDuPoste}}</td>
              <td>{{ grid.Emploie}}</td>
              <td>{{ grid.Metier  }}</td>
              <td>{{grid.Famille}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the search and number of data displayed not working.
PS: my data coming from php script.

here is a screenshot : http://hpics.li/efa3c31

Answer (score 2):

Notice here that you are accessing the DOM using jQuery in the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook.

**ngOnInit()**

> Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the
>   data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input
>   properties. Called once, after the first ngOnChanges(). -- https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

But in your case the component's view must be rendered before you can access the DOM.

**ngAfterViewInit()**

> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child
>   views. Called once after the first ngAfterContentChecked(). -- https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

You should modify the `CartographieComponent`'s code like this:

```
import {AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

// other imports here

export class CartographieComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  // other code here

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    const el = $(this.rootNode.nativeElement).find('#example')[0];
    $('#example').DataTable();
  }

}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi Abrar , Thanks for your answer , I tried your solution but nothing change and still not work !